# Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack to select Divs by class

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using C# with HtmlAgilityPack and I can select divs that have an id of foo

```
var foos = from foo in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
           where foo.Id == "foo" 
           select foo;
```

but how do I select div's with a class of bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use XPATH like this

```
//div[@class='bar']
```

or

```
//*/div[@class='bar']
```

You also may be able to do && `foo.Class == "bar"`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no foo.Class how would I use xpath instead?

Comment: Got it.: var foos = from foo in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='bar']")
select foo;

Comment: @NicholasMurray Do you need the LINQ in that statement? Isn't it redundant?